# Python 3.9.7 - How to continue through a function when if statement returns true?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am fairly new to python, and I can't figure out if this is possible. I have a function where I want to check conditions, but continue checking the rest of the conditions even when one is true. For example:

```
    def function(n):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            print("Number is even")
        if n >= 10:
            print("Number is at least two digits")
        if n % 3 == 0:
            print("3 is a divisor of number")
```

If I were to input a number like 9, the output would be:

`3 is a divisor of number`

but if I put in 30, it would print:

`Number is even`

rather than my desired output of all three statements:

`Number is even`

`Number is at least two digits`

`3 is a divisor of number`

I know that I can't do this:

```
    def function(n):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            print("Number is even")
            if n >= 10:
                print("Number is at least two digits")
                if n % 3 == 0:
                    print("3 is a divisor of number")
```

because an input of a number like 15 would output nothing, instead of the two statements that apply to it.

I have researched quite a bit, and there seems to be no other related questions or articles that are easy to find. Again, I am new to python(and programming in general, have been slowly learning for about a month) and there may be some terminology that I do not know to search. The most similar posts on here I could find were:

[Can I continue an IF-ELSE statement through a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169971/can-i-continue-an-if-else-statement-through-a-function)

and

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757965/how-to-have-multiple-conditions-for-one-if-statement-in-python[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757965/how-to-have-multiple-conditions-for-one-if-statement-in-python%5B2%5D)

as well as many other websites trying to only explain if, elif, and else statements to me, like [Python’s cascaded if statement: test multiple conditions after each other](https://kodify.net/python/if-else/cascaded-if/) but with no clarification on whether or not this is possible. Any help would be appreciated, or an alternative method to getting around this restriction.

Comment: This is a really stupid question, but please do not downvote it so I lose my posting privilege. I'm new and just trying to learn. I apologize for not testing out toned down code first, it didn't even cross my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already does exactly what you want:

```py
In [1]: def function(n):
   ...:     if n % 2 == 0:
   ...:         print("Number is even")
   ...:     if n >= 10:
   ...:         print("Number is at least two digits")
   ...:     if n % 3 == 0:
   ...:         print("3 is a divisor of number")
   ...:

In [2]: function(30)
Number is even
Number is at least two digits
3 is a divisor of number

In [3]: function(15)
Number is at least two digits
3 is a divisor of number

In [4]: function(9)
3 is a divisor of number
```

Comment: Thanks. I accidentally reversed my thought process while writing that test code, as I was simplifying a much larger function to make it easier. Is the proper thing to do to edit my question or to create a new one?

Comment: Go ahead and edit your current post.

Comment: Agh nevermind it must be some other error within my function. Everything seems to be working when I dumb it down. I guess I know to try that in the future before posting here. Thanks for the help though. I guess deleting my question is the best thing to do now. I don't want to lost all of my 9 rep from this.